# What is the relay-chain name for Kusama for chain-spec?

Tags: polkadot, kusama

Working on final touches for chain-spec to create a parathread on kusama. What is the relay-chain name for kusama? kusama or kusama-native?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chain name for the Kusama relay-chain is `kusama`. The `kusama-native` is a feature you might want to enable when building your own Kusama spec.

For the purpose of preparing a parathread chainspec, it is sufficient to provide the Kusama relay spec with `--chain=kusama`.